# Copy paste GUI in CKEditor through Chrome

Tags: ckeditor

How do I make my CKEditor to not allow GUI copy pasting into it? Currently I am copy pasting\drag and dropping GUI in CKEditor, i just want to avoid it.I do not want my CKEditor note to allow copy paste or drag and drop GUI in editor,how do I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to prevent pasting into CKEditor I believe you need to use below code or something similar but the key is canceling the `paste` event:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {});
editor.on( 'paste', function( evt ){
    evt.cancel();
});
```